# SwiftUI NavigationView cannot appears multiple NavigationLinks

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, swiftui-navigationview

I have a navigation view and each NavigationLink jumps to a color view:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    private let navigationLinks: [NavigationItem] = [
        NavigationItem("Red", AnyView(Color.red.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))),
        NavigationItem("Orange", AnyView(Color.orange.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))),
        NavigationItem("Yellow", AnyView(Color.yellow.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))),
        NavigationItem("Green", AnyView(Color.green.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))),
        NavigationItem("Blue", AnyView(Color.blue.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))),
        NavigationItem("Purple", AnyView(Color.purple.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))),
        NavigationItem("Pink", AnyView(Color.pink.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))),
        NavigationItem("Cyan", AnyView(Color.cyan.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))),
        NavigationItem("Teal", AnyView(Color.teal.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))),
        NavigationItem("Black", AnyView(Color.black.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))),
        NavigationItem("Gray", AnyView(Color.gray.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all))),
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ForEach(self.navigationLinks, id:\.key) { item in
                NavigationLink(destination: item.value) {
                    Text(item.key)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct NavigationItem {
    let key: String
    let value: AnyView
    init(_ key: String, _ value: AnyView) {
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
    }
}
```

The result of running the program is just an Orange Item, and the other NavigationItems have disappeared.
[image]

When I click the back button in the upper left corner it will go back to the Red Item.
[image]
[image]

Is there any work around for this?

Comment: Don’t use AnyView

Comment: Do you have a better way? If I don't use AnyView, how can NavigationItem.value receive any type of view? I have tried generics:

NavigationItem<T: View> {
    let key: String
    let value: T
    init(_ key: String, _ value: T) {
        self.key = key
        self.value = value
    }
}

But initializing the navigationLinks array causes a compile error. @loremipsum

Comment: let navigationLinks = [ NavigationItem("Red", Color.red.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)), NavigationItem("Orange", Color.orange.edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)) ] ; Error message: Property definition has inferred type '[NavigationItem<some View>]', involving the 'some' return type of another declaration. @loremipsum

Comment: Watch demytifying SwiftUI, any setup that requires AnyView is a bad setup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current `ForEach` will directly add all `Text` to `NavigationView` and this makes `NavigationView` confused. Wrap your `ForEach` to either `List` or `VStack`.

```
List { //Or VStack {
    ForEach(self.navigationLinks, id:\.key) { item in
        NavigationLink(destination: item.value) {
            Text(item.key)
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** With `VStack` you don't have scroll so if you are planning to add more items or a dynamic list then it's better to use `List` View only.